chrome extension to limit tabs in specific window?
is it possible to create a chrome extenstion that can limit tab to THAT specific window?
i have some websites, where i want them to REMAIN the ONLY one in that window
all tab limiter extensions currently apply limits to all windows.
any workarounds?

Tab limiter helps you get back control over your browsing – by limiting the number of tabs you can open at once. You can specify the number of tabs in total and per window. Moreover, you can show a customizable message when the tab limit is hit.
